# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError . Angular 2(5) *ngIf

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-if

I'm using a service to pass data between child and parent with the purpose being to update the parent ui with child specific info depending on what child is loaded.

Service:

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";

export class ChildDataService {
  private childDetails = new Subject<{}>();

  childLoaded$ = this.childDetails.asObservable();
  changedComponentName(option: {}){
    this.childDetails.next(option);
  }
}
```

Parent Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildDataService } from "../core/helpers/child-data.service";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Subscription";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  childDetails: {title?: string};

  private subscription:Subscription;

  constructor( private childDataService: ChildDataService) {
    this.childDataService.childLoaded$.subscribe(
      newChildDetails => {
        console.log(newChildDetails);
        this.childDetails = newChildDetails
      });
  }
}
```

Example Child Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildDataService } from "../../core/helpers/child-data.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './child-dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child-dashboard.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class ChildDashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private childDataService: ChildDataService) { }

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.childDataService.changedComponentName({
      title: 'Dashboard'
    });
  }
}
```

Parent HTML:

```
<div class="subheader">
  <h1>{{ childDetails?.title }}</h1>
  <button *ngIf="childDetails?.title == 'Dashboard'">dashboard</button>
  <button *ngIf="childDetails?.title == 'SecondChild'">Second Child</button>
</div>
```

With this setup I am getting the error "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError" when i click on a routerLink, now if i click on the same link a second time, the error persists but the correct button becomes visible.  Spent all weekend getting nowhere with this, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ngOnInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.childDataService.changedComponentName({
          title: 'Dashboard'
        }), {});
}
```

it should work.

```
async ngOnInit() {
   await this.childDataService.changedComponentName({
            title: 'Dashboard'
         });
}
```

Comment: Had tried this, or similar over the course of my experiments. Unfortunately it has no effect.

Comment: Edited Answer.. Try this one. The problem is that the page is loaded before the component rendering. Have you tried `ngAfterViewInit` too?

Comment: haven't even heard of 'ngAfterViewInit' , but after reading up it looks like it certainly could be a step in the right direction.  Cheers, will update progress.